# how do I call a shell script and select an option automatically using a shell script?

Tags: shell-script

To explain better; There's a shell script example.sh that upon execution creates a menu:

```
0. do this
1. do that
```

I want to create a batch script that calls example.sh then selects one of the options.

I tried the below it just opens the script.

```
./example.sh; 0
./example.sh; echo 0
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to call anoter script with parameters  or build another script dynamically & lanch it if build is OK ?

Comment: This will depend on how the script works. Can you share the script here? Even better, can you just share a small part of the script that is enough to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can dive into "expect" (or some modern derivatives) that are meant to programmatically interact with text based programs.

Answer (score 0):

You *probably* want:

```bsh
echo 0 | ./example.sh
```

This will send the string `0\n` to the script's standard input.

Your attempts are misguided: with `./example.sh; exit 0` the shell will

- first run the script,
- then, *after it ends*, will run the `echo 0` command

Comment: Aw! thank you. If i want to run multiple choices one after another, I assume I could: echo 1 | ./example.sh; echo 0 | ./example.sh

Comment: No, you would do `printf "%s\n" choice1 choice2 choice3 etc | ./example.sh` -- you only want to run the script once, giving it ALL the input.